# How to UPDATE from JOIN with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, update, group-by, query

In a `SELECT` query of

```
SELECT b.id, MIN(IFNULL(a.views,0)) AS counted 
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id GROUP BY id 
HAVING counted>0
```

How can I turn this query to `UPDATE` as

```
UPDATE b.number = counted
```

Comment: Update query with left join and group by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022405/mysql-update-query-with-left-join-and-group-by

Comment: `counted` is the result of an aggregation, so how do you determine which row in table2/b to update? is it possible that you could update multiple rows with the same `counted` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE table2 AS b1, ( SELECT b.id, MIN(IFNULL(a.views, 0)) AS counted 
                       FROM table1 a 
                       JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id 
                       GROUP BY id 
                       HAVING counted > 0 ) AS b2
SET b1.number = b2.counted
WHERE b1.id = b2.id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    UPDATE table2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(IFNULL(table1.views,0)) counted
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY table1.id
    HAVING counted>0
    ) x ON x.id = table2.id
    SET table2.number = x.counted
```

Comment: How's that different from the earlier, accepted answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE table2 SET table2.number = x.counted  FROM table2
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(IFNULL(table1.views,0)) counted,id
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.id
HAVING counted>0
) x ON x.id = table2.id
```

Try this also.

Comment: Hi Anwar, its best to explain, in your answer,  whats different or why it works